# Expectation of sequences of random variables that converge to 0 in probability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, asymptotics

Let $X_n, n \geq 1$ be a sequence of random variables that converges to zero in probability, that is, $\forall \varepsilon >0$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n| < \varepsilon) = 1$$
Moreover, let $X_n=o_p(n^{-1})$, that is, $\forall \varepsilon >0$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}{n^{-1}}\right| < \varepsilon\right) = 1,$$
or equivalently,
$\forall \varepsilon, \eta >0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$,
$$P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}{n^{-1}}\right| < \varepsilon\right) \geq 1-\eta,$$

My question is, what can we say about $E(X_n)$ when $n \to \infty$? For instance, is it true that $E(X_n)=o(n^{-1})$? Or more generally, is it true that $E(o_p(n^{-1}))=o(n^{-1})$? How can I prove so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, you cannot say anything like that. Consider $(X_n)_n$ defined as $$X_n=\begin{cases}0 &\text{ w.p. } 1-
 \frac{1}{n}\\ n^2 &\text{ w.p. }\frac{1}{n}\end{cases}$$

Then $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$ *(and tweaking the example above, you can replace the growth rate $n$ by anything you'd like)*, but, for any $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ n\lvert X_n\rvert < \varepsilon \}
\geq 1-\frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1.
$$

Comment: Can you figure if there is any assumption we can make such that my theory holds?

Comment: @SlayingTitans Uniform integrability (UI) should do the trick for you I believe. You want to prevent things from going wrong on small sets and that's the typical condition to do that. Certainly convergence in probability and UI implies convergence in expectation, but I'm not 100% sure that will extend to your exact theorem.

Comment: Boundedness should be sufficient  (quite a strong assumption).

Comment: @ClementC. I think boundedness should be much stronger than necessary. Domination by an $Y \in L_1$ is probably stronger than necessary, don't you think?

Comment: And under any of these two conditions, how would go about proving it? I can't figure out an inequality to use, for the life of me.

Comment: For the (overkill) boundedness assumption, say $\lvert X_n\rvert\leq A$ a.s. for all $n$: $$\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n\rvert ] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X_n\rvert \geq x\} dx \leq \int_0^\varepsilon 1dx + \int_\varepsilon^A\mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X_n\rvert \geq \varepsilon\} dx = \varepsilon + A\mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X_n\rvert \geq \varepsilon\}$$ which is going to be at most $2\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq n_\varepsilon$.

Comment: @David That may be the case -- my brain is currently too fried to see how to prove that.

Comment: @SlayingTitans have you looked into extending Vitali convergence theorem to your 'little-o' condition. Vitali convergence theorem gives us that if $\{X_n\}$ is U.I. and $X_n \to 0, i.p.$ that $E(X_n)\to 0.$ There may be a simple way to show that the convergence rate carries over from the $i.p.$ to the $L_1$ convergence, but I haven't had time to give it any real thought. If you can't demonstrate it, I would suggest posting a new question asking if it is a sufficient condition, it would be interesting in it's own regard to have as a stand alone question.